# Entity Framework Code first development Resources and Documentation

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first

I know EF4 is still in development but as a newcomer to the subject, I need a document, tutorial etc. with EF 4 code first approach. All the info is in EF 4 Team Blog but scattered around different posts. A full coverage would be really nice.

Any one knows of a such place?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best online resource that I've seen so far is *[Scott Guthrie](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu)* series of blogs on the new EF “code first” development option:

**[Code-First Development with Entity Framework 4](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4)**

**[Entity Framework 4 “Code-First”: Custom Database Schema Mapping](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping)**

**[Using EF “Code First” with an Existing Database](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database)**

If you are new to the subject, like you said, then they will be a perfect point to start. There is no online documentation on MSDN for the code first API by the way, as it's merely a CTP and subject to be changed.

After that you can check out the *[ADO.NET team blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/)* on the Code First Development:

**[Entity Framework Feature CTP4 Released](https://web.archive.org/web/20160502104003/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/14/ctp4announcement.aspx)**

**[EF Feature CTP4 Walkthrough: Productivity Improvements](https://web.archive.org/web/20160502112606/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/14/ctp4piwalkthrough.aspx)**

[**EF Feature CTP4 Walkthrough: Code First**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160703021543/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/14/ctp4codefirstwalkthrough.aspx)


[*Entity Framework Design blog*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/) is also a great place to share ideas and give feedback to EF team. They also have the following posts on Code First so far:

[**Productivity Improvements for the Entity Framework**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160223203539/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/21/productivity-improvements-for-the-entity-framework.aspx)

[**Conventions for Code-First**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160218232218/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx)

[**Data Annotations in the Entity Framework and Code First**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204044444/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx)

Comment: This is a good video from Chanel9 http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2010/DEV212