# Entity Framework Code First: How to map private fields?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to map a table column to a class field instead to a class property and how?

**YOU CAN DO IT :)**

Follow this link: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2013/08/22/mapping-non-public-members-with-entity-framework-code-first.aspx

This is a common request, and really makes sense; we need to use LINQ expressions and a bit of reflection magic. First, an helper function for returning an expression that points to a member:

```
      public static class ExpressionHelper
      {
          public static Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> GetMember<TEntity, TResult>(String memberName)
          {
              ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "p");
              MemberExpression member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(TEntity).GetMember(memberName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single());
              Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TResult>>(member, parameter);
              return (expression);
          }
     }
```

Then, we call it on the DbContext.OnModelCreating method, as a parameter to StructuralTypeConfiguration.Property:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(ExpressionHelper.GetMember<Project, Decimal>("Budget")).IsRequired();

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity Framework (Code First or not) does not support mapping to a field; only to properties.

**UPDATE**
As pointed out in the comments, these documents are a bit dated but might still help any beginner along:

> [Entity Framework Code first development Resources and Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803610/entity-framework-code-first-development-resources-and-documentation/3805975#3805975)

For the sake of completeness, heres a link to whats included in EF 4.1 RC: [EF 4.1 Release Candidate Available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx)

Changes since CTP5 (From the link above):

> - **Rename of ‘DbDatabase’** to ‘Database’. This class has also moved
>   to the  ‘System.Data.Entity’
>   namespace, along with the database
>   initializer classes.
> - **Rename of ‘ModelBuilder’** to ‘DbModelBuilder’, to align with the
>   other core classes.
> - **Validation in Model First and Database First.** The new validation
>   feature was only supported in Code
>   First in CTP5. In RC the validation
>   feature will work with all three
>   development workflows (Model First,
>   Database First, and Code First).
> - **Complete Intellisense docs.** Feature CTPs were not extensively documented
>   because the API surface was changing
>   significantly between each release.
>   This release includes complete
>   documentation.
> - **Removal of Code First Pluggable Conventions.** Pluggable Conventions
>   were previewed in Feature CTP5 but
>   were not at go-live quality for this
>   release. This release still supports
>   the removal of default conventions.
> - **Consolidation of IsIndependent** in the Code First relationship API. When
>   configuring relationships in Feature
>   CTP5 the IsIndependent method was used
>   to identify that the relationship did
>   not have a foreign key property
>   exposed in the object model. This is
>   now done by calling the Map method.
>   HasForeignKey is still used for
>   relationships where the foreign key
>   property is exposed in the object
>   model.

Comment: +1 I'm agree. I've been searching for a link that explain it before posting, but I Didn't found it. Anyway, I'm pretty sure this is how EF works.

Comment: I have already read all these documents. Btw, they are old. The new RC even has breaking changes. That's why I ask. ef ef es

Comment: It's true that there are braking changes, but support for mapping to fields was not in the agenda AFAIK. And sorry for the dated documents, didn't know the level of your EF knowledge and thought they might be useful anyway.

Comment: 10x Sergi, it is sad field mapping would not be possible soon. I think we will go back to NHibernate.

Comment: @mynknow - Just out of curiosity, why do you want to map to a field? You could map to a private property, no problem there...

Comment: I remember reading a couple of posts about it but can't seem to find them anywhere now. Got his one, but it applies to CTP4. It might make your eyes water: http://blog.cincura.net/232147-mapping-private-or-protected-properties-with-code-first-efv4-ctp4/
In there, look for the comment of "Drew Jones" for a CTP5 example. That might be stuff for another question altogether though...

Comment: I will try. I want to expose my collections as IEnumerable or AsReadonly so they do not get modified trough the property. I have special add/remove methods to deal with the collections (fire event for example). thank you