# Map to an Entity with fields instead of properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is it possible to tell EF to map to a Class with fields instead of a class with Properties?

The Entity is then used by Filehelpers to create File, That's why I'm unfortunately bound to fields.

We have a lot of Entities, with a lot of Properties and a lot of Data, so remapping them or working with a backing field is not really an option.

Any suggestions or tricks?

```
public class MyUnmappedEntity
{
  public string Name;
}

var data = app.Database.SqlQuery<MyUnmappedEntity>("SELECT * FROM MyTable").ToList();
```

Comment: Why dont you have the EF Model classes separate from your business classes? You can go for "Code first from database" approach which would set up all the model classes with relations for you. Then you can use EF as you normally do and may be have a mapping logic t convert it to your business classes.

Comment: Some of the EF properties can refer to objects or collections an need to be virtual so they can be overridden by the proxy classes. I don't know Filehelpers or why it only works with fields, but create new classes for that and look at something like Automapper to populate them from the EF Models.

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377722/entity-framework-code-first-how-to-map-private-fields I am not sure OP really means `fields` though.

Comment: I wonder if FileHelpers would work with dynamically Emitted types. If it does, you could work on a solution to define Classes with properties for Entity Framework and then Emit new classes with Fields corresponding to each property to work with FileHelpers.

Comment: @Developer I usally do, however in this special casei can't do it because of performance reasons and maintenability.

Comment: @gsharp - IMO having separate models will be more maintainable IMO vs implementing a hack solution. Hopefully someone might come up with a great idea, lets wait :)

Comment: @Developer there are more than 300 columns spreaded over 15 entities that basically only do read from db, some formatting over the file helpers attributes and then written into the file. You really don't wanna maintain them twice ;-) I ended up by using DbDataReader and a bit of expression trees for doing the mapping to my fields.

Comment: Why dont you post your answer so that it helps others as well?